# Align fotorama thumbnails to the left

Tags: css, alignment, fotorama

This question has been asked before: [Start the thumbnails from the left of the slideshow instead of the middle](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30867297/4220943),  but there's no answer yet.

I'm trying to get the thumbnail bar at the bottom to align the thumbnails to the left when fotorama is loaded. By default, it's centered.

Answer (score 0):

As I answered it here, [Start the thumbnails from the left of the slideshow instead of the middle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30867297/start-the-thumbnails-from-the-left-of-the-sldieshow-instead-of-middle-of-the-sli/33062159#33062159), It is simple. The fotorama plugin uses css3 transform property to align thumbnails under the main image. just calculate the parent width and children container width using jQuery and if the parent is wider than children container, make a transform across X axis to shift all thumbnails to the left.

**EDIT:**
I made an edit that when you click on on arrows or thumbnails, it also does the alignment fix!

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var pw = $('.fotorama__nav--thumbs').innerWidth();
    var cw = $('.fotorama__nav__shaft').innerWidth();
    var offset = pw -cw;
    var negOffset = (-1 * offset) / 2;
    var totalOffset = negOffset + 'px';
    if (pw > cw) {
      $('.fotorama__nav__shaft').css('transform', 'translate3d(' + totalOffset + ', 0, 0)');
    }
    $('.fotorama__nav__frame--thumb, .fotorama__arr, .fotorama__stage__frame, .fotorama__img, .fotorama__stage__shaft').click(function() {
      if (pw > cw) {
        $('.fotorama__nav__shaft').css('transform', 'translate3d(' + totalOffset + ', 0, 0)');
      }
    });
  });
```

Comment: Thanks @farzad-yz The calculation works fine at the on set and does shift the thumbnails to the left when the page is loaded. But when I click on the thumbails to navigate between thumbnails, or the navigation arrows, the whole thumbnail (`.fotorama__nav__shaft`) moves to center again. Looks like the transform is resetting to `translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px)` when I click on it.

Comment: Thanks! That solves the click issue. I'm sorry to bother you again, but now if the window is resized, the thumbnails again reset and move back to the middle.

Is it because of the changing width of the parent container? Is fotorama recalculating every time the width is changed? How can that be incorporated into your code? I've tried using a `.resize` but no luck

Comment: While I'll be working on the resize issue, please accept my answer.

Comment: Hi @farzad-yz, Any luck?

Answer (score 0):

Just add to CSS that code:

```
.fotorama__nav {
    text-align: left or right !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've just set

```
.fotorama__nav__shaft {
  display: block;
}
```